# I want to change the color of focused otp text field's single element in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

In my OTP text field, the focused color of the bottom border of a single element, or textfield is blue by default. How can i change it to orange?? Also how can i change the unfocused color of that border from black to white. That is by default, without entering any number, color of all blocks or bottom border is white??? I will highlight the property in the image.

Check out this image, if you didn't understand properly that what i am trying to say - [MobileImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVUCu.jpg)

Here's the code -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:otp_text_field/style.dart';

class OTPTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Number of the OTP Fields
  final int length;

  /// Total Width of the OTP Text Field
  final double width;

  /// Width of the single OTP Field
  final double fieldWidth;

  /// Manage the type of keyboard that shows up
  TextInputType keyboardType;

  /// The style to use for the text being edited.
  final TextStyle style;

  /// Text Field Alignment
  /// default: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween [MainAxisAlignment]
  final MainAxisAlignment textFieldAlignment;

  /// Obscure Text if data is sensitive
  final bool obscureText;

  /// Text Field Style for field shape.
  /// default FieldStyle.underline [FieldStyle]
  final FieldStyle fieldStyle;

  /// Callback function, called when a change is detected to the pin.
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;

  /// Callback function, called when pin is completed.
  final ValueChanged<String> onCompleted;

  OTPTextField(
      {Key key,
      this.length = 4,
      this.width = 20,
      this.fieldWidth = 50,
      this.keyboardType = TextInputType.number,
      this.style = const TextStyle(),
      this.textFieldAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      this.obscureText = false,
      this.fieldStyle = FieldStyle.underline,
      this.onChanged,
      this.onCompleted})
      : assert(length > 1);

  @override
  _OTPTextFieldState createState() => _OTPTextFieldState();
}

class _OTPTextFieldState extends State<OTPTextField> {
  List<FocusNode> _focusNodes;
  List<TextEditingController> _textControllers;

  List<Widget> _textFields;
  List<String> _pin;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNodes = List<FocusNode>(widget.length);
    _textControllers = List<TextEditingController>(widget.length);

    _pin = List.generate(widget.length, (int i) {
      return '';
    });
    _textFields = List.generate(widget.length, (int i) {
      return buildTextField(context, i);
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textControllers
        .forEach((TextEditingController controller) => controller.dispose());
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: widget.width,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: widget.textFieldAlignment,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: _textFields,
      ),
    );
  }

  /// This function Build and returns individual TextField item.
  ///
  /// * Requires a build context
  /// * Requires Int position of the field
  Widget buildTextField(BuildContext context, int i) {
    if (_focusNodes[i] == null) _focusNodes[i] = new FocusNode();

    if (_textControllers[i] == null)
      _textControllers[i] = new TextEditingController();

    return Container(
      width: widget.fieldWidth,
      child: TextField(
        cursorColor: Colors.white,
        controller: _textControllers[i],
        keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        maxLength: 1,
        style: widget.style,
        focusNode: _focusNodes[i],
        obscureText: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          fillColor: Colors.white,
            counterText: "",
            border: widget.fieldStyle == FieldStyle.box
                ? OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 4.0, color: Colors.green))
                : null),
        onChanged: (String str) {
          // Check if the current value at this position is empty
          // If it is move focus to previous text field.
          if (str.isEmpty) {
            if (i == 0) return;
            _focusNodes[i].unfocus();
            _focusNodes[i - 1].requestFocus();
          }

          // Update the current pin
          setState(() {
            _pin[i] = str;
          });

          // Remove focus
          if (str.isNotEmpty) _focusNodes[i].unfocus();
          // Set focus to the next field if available
          if (i + 1 != widget.length && str.isNotEmpty)
            FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodes[i + 1]);

          String currentPin = "";
          _pin.forEach((String value) {
            currentPin += value;
          });

          // if there are no null values that means otp is completed
          // Call the `onCompleted` callback function provided
          if (!_pin.contains(null) &&
              !_pin.contains('') &&
              currentPin.length == widget.length) {
            widget.onCompleted(currentPin);
          }

          // Call the `onChanged` callback function
          widget.onChanged(currentPin);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your default `Theme` color is blue, this will be applied to your `TextField`. You would need to change your Theme color for your `TextField` to change your border color. Take note that this will only change the Theme color for `TextField` and not for your whole Flutter app.

```
child: Theme(
          data: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            primaryColorDark: Colors.orange,
          ),
          child: TextField(
            ...
          ));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/otp_text_field/example)
Easy fix is by adding the otpFieldStyle property and edit the colors as preferred for example:

```
  Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:18.0),
        child: OTPTextField(
          length: 4,
           width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
           textFieldAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
           fieldWidth: 55,
           fieldStyle: FieldStyle.underline,
           otpFieldStyle: OtpFieldStyle(
                  focusBorderColor: Colors.orange //(here)
           ),
           outlineBorderRadius: 15,
           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.white, ),
           onChanged: (pin) {
                  print("Changed: " + pin);
           },
           onCompleted: (pin) {
                  print("Completed: " + pin);
           }),
          ),
```

which has more properties as below

```
OtpFieldStyle(
  {this.backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  this.borderColor: Colors.black26,
  this.focusBorderColor: Colors.blue,
  this.disabledBorderColor: Colors.grey,
  this.enabledBorderColor: Colors.black26,
  this.errorBorderColor: Colors.red});
```